# Pharo 2.0 not running on CentOS 6.6

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I am trying to run my pharo2.0 application on CentoOS which was previously been installed in a mac. The original version is pharo2.0 so I need to run the same image CentoOS too, but I get an error which says this below :

```
/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by xxxxx)
```

Should I be trying to upgrade the CentoOS and see if pharo2.0 works or port  my whole application to a later version of pharo?

Answer (score 2):

There is now a VM build especially for systems with an older libc version. In fact there is a build for Centos specifically (which has a slight variation in linkages from Debian), the latest version of which is permalinked [here](http://files.pharo.org/vm/pharo/linux/centos/latest.zip). See http://pharo.org/download#custom for more info.